# How can I convert a Google Site to PDF or ODF?

Tags: google-sites

I created a documentation site on Google Sites, and now I have to hand in that as a printed Document. I need all pages in the site converted to PDF to take to a printer, and I'm now realizing that GDocs has no "export as document" option. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I am also looking for the same functionality for the same reason (using Google Sites as a documentation wiki). Best I can recommend is editing the HTML raw to include a print style to at least collapse menus :(

Answer (score 0):

Not really a programming question, but you could install something like [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) and print the document directly to PDF.  This software basically adds a new printer driver and asks you for a file name, producing a PDF rather than a printed hard copy.

Comment: Actually, that works as you say with google docs, but not with google sites.

Answer (score 0):

If I log into my google documents and select a document, then a "more activities" -> Export then I can store the doc locally.

Perhaps the wording don't match up, I use a swedish gui, and just did a direct translation...

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just click

```
ctrl+P
```

this would run the print command and then click on "save as pdf"? 
I guess this should do it if I understand your question correctly.